# How to add json property to a Json.net Array

Tags: c#, json, ajax, list, each

I want to add a property to the List  in C#, then I want to create a JObject to set the value and sum some values ​​after, then I need to convert my `List <Object>` to a `JArray`, then to I want To add my jsonObject to JArray, then to return my JArray in Json form for display on screen or to go througt the JsonArray to show each  result on a javascript table, but at the end the only thing I get is this error:

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length'
>   in [{"client":{"id":1001,"debtJanuary":500000"....

```
double total = 0;
JArray jsonarray = null;   
JObject  jsonobject = null;
List<ClientAccount> list = null;

try
{
    list = ClientBussinesLayer.getListClientCash(id);

    for(ClientAccount item in list)
    {
        total += item.debtJanuary + item.debtFebruary + item.debtMarch;
    }

    jsonobject = new JObject();
    jsonobject.Add("totalDebt", total);
    jsonobject.Add("statusList", "success");


    jsonarray = JArray.FromObject(list); 
    jsonarray.Add(jsonObject); 

}catch(Exception ex)
{
    error
}

return  JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonarray);


fnSuccessList: function (data) {

    var strHtml = '';
    var list = jQuery.parseJSON(data);  //also i tried with data.d but dont work

    $.each(list, function (index, item) {
        strHtml += '<tr>';
        strHtml += '  <td>' + item.debtJanuary + '</td>';
        strHtml += '  <td>' + item.debtFebruary + '</td>';
        strHtml += '  <td>' + item.debtMarch + '</td>';
        strHtml += '</tr>'
    });


    $("#table").append(strHtml);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use foreach loop instead for:

```
foreach(var item in list)
    {
         total += item.debtJanuary+item.debtFebruary + item.debtMarch;
    }
```